# Android Manifest . The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have looked through other questions regarding the same problem but was unable to find a helpful solution. Here is my xml . What is wrong with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.projextxy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogInActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.projextxy" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.projextxy"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the last manifest tag `</manifest>` after your application tag

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projextxy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LogInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.projextxy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.projextxy"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I added the </manifest> tag but still the error is showing up.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code you gave me . Now a new error shows up "XML document structures must start and end with the same entity " .

Comment: Just check all your tags once .Make your you are closing all the tags too (except xml tag). Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: Looked through everything and double checked that all tags except xml are closed. Still no results.